# Replace duplicates on axis 0 with 0

Tags: pandas, numpy

The ID represents levels of the same thing. This means that the dataset has many duplicates in each sample. I want to keep the longest ID value as this contains the most information.

```
df_test=pd.DataFrame({'ID':[
                            "k__",
                           "k__|p__|c__|o__",
                           "k__|p__|c__|o__|f__",
                           "k__|p__|c__|o__|f__|g_",
                           "k__|p__|c__|o__|f__|g_|s__",
                           "k__|p__|c__|o__|f__|g_|s__|a"],
                      'sample_1':[95,3.64,3.64,3.1,3.1,3.1],
                     'sample_2':[93,2.45,2.45,4.5,4.5,4.5],
                     'sample_3':[93,2.45,2.45,4.5,4.5,7.5]})
```

```
            ID                      sample_1     sample_2   sample_3
    0   k__                          95.00        93.00       93.00
    1   k__|p__|c__|o__               3.64         2.45        2.45
    2   k__|p__|c__|o__|f__           3.64         2.45        2.45
    3   k__|p__|c__|o__|f__|g_        3.10         4.50        4.50
    4   k__|p__|c__|o__|f__|g_|s__    3.10         4.50        4.50
    5   k__|p__|c__|o__|f__|g_|s__|a  3.10         4.50        7.50
```

How I was handling this is to drop the duplicates, keep the last occurrence of the duplicate (which contains the most data in the ID column) and subset by sample:

```
sample_cols = [col for col in df_test.columns if 'sample' in col]
df_test.drop_duplicates(subset=sample_cols, keep='last')
```

```
     ID                           sample_1   sample_2    sample_3
 0   k__                            95.00     93.00       93.00
 2   k__|p__|c__|o__|f__             3.64      2.45        2.45
 4   k__|p__|c__|o__|f__|g_|s__      3.10      4.50        4.50
 5   k__|p__|c__|o__|f__|g_|s__|a    3.10      4.50        7.50
```

What is happening though at index 4 and 5 for sample 1 and 2 is that duplicate values are remaining when another column or sample contains a different value.

Is there a way in pandas to check if duplicate values occur on 0 axis to fill the last occurrence with 0:

```
     ID                           sample_1   sample_2    sample_3
 0   k__                            95.00     93.00       93.00
 2   k__|p__|c__|o__|f__             3.64      2.45        2.45
 4   k__|p__|c__|o__|f__|g_|s__      0         0           4.50
 5   k__|p__|c__|o__|f__|g_|s__|a    3.10      4.50        7.50
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used `df.duplicated`: [documentation on pandas duplicated](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html):

First Removing the duplicates and keeping the last line (works the same as in your code, just a one-liner):

```
df_test = df_test[df_test.iloc[:,1:].duplicated(keep = 'last') == False]
df_test

ID                                  sample_1  sample_2  sample_3
0   k__                             95.00     93.00     93.00
2   k__|p__|c__|o__|f__             3.64      2.45      2.45
4   k__|p__|c__|o__|f__|g_|s__      3.10      4.50      4.50
5   k__|p__|c__|o__|f__|g_|s__|a    3.10      4.50      7.50
```

Then for the replacement with zero:

```
for sample in df_test.iloc[:,1:]:
    df_test.loc[df_test[sample].duplicated(keep = 'last'), sample] = 0
df_test

    ID                              sample_1    sample_2    sample_3
0   k__                             95.00       93.00       93.00
2   k__|p__|c__|o__|f__             3.64        2.45        2.45
4   k__|p__|c__|o__|f__|g_|s__      0.00        0.00        4.50
5   k__|p__|c__|o__|f__|g_|s__|a    3.10        4.50        7.50
```

It does come out with a warning, which I was not able to avoid, but it does work as intended